# Getting invalid operation: mymap["title"] (type interface {} does not support indexing) when trying to index a map

Tags: dictionary, go

I have data that's in a map, and I want to index into the map by key to get a value.

```
mdi, err := page.Metadata()
fmt.Println(mdi["title"])
```

However I keep getting the error message `invalid operation: mdi["title"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`. I am confused, because the data is a map and I should be able to index into it to get the value. In case the type wasn't clear, I also tried to cast the value to a string:

```
title, ok := mdi["title"].(string)
checkOk(ok)
fmt.Println(title)
```

However, I got the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The data type here was the key. `mdi` was not actually a map, but an `interface{}`, which could be anything - a map, a string, an int. You need to assert it to a map with expected key/value types first, or do the awkward `case` switch outlined in [JSON and Go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

```
mdi, err := page.Metadata()
md, ok := mdi.(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(md["title"])
```

Comment: This is not a cast but a type assertion.

Comment: @DaveC could you please explain this in more details `This is not a cast but a type assertion`. Why golang need type assertion and why not directly give result if casting not required. It can give an error if it fails to perform the required cast. But why it need `type assertion` if `casting` is not required.

Comment: I think you are coming from a dynamically typed language. From what I can understand from the code you posted, it seems Metadata() is written to return an interface{} and not a map. If you change it to return a map, your code will work fine. It is interface, then caller has to first know the actual type of return value, so that it can allow operations specific to that type on value. Any type by default is an interface type so you cannot do any individual type specific operations on an interface. @PrakashPandey

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have control over what `page.Metadata` does, but if you do, a better way is available for this situation. Say your code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "log"
)

func Metadata() (interface{}, error) {
   y := []byte(`{"metadata": {"title": "Stack Overflow"}}`)
   var m map[string]interface{}
   e := json.Unmarshal(y, &m)
   if e != nil {
      return nil, e
   }
   return m["metadata"], nil
}

func main() {
   m, e := Metadata()
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
   s := m["title"]
   println(s == "Stack Overflow")
}
```

You'd get the same error you got. But you can change it to this:

```
type Map map[string]interface{}

func (m Map) M(s string) Map {
   return m[s].(map[string]interface{})
}

func (m Map) S(s string) string {
   return m[s].(string)
}

func Metadata() (Map, error) {
   y := []byte(`{"metadata": {"title": "Stack Overflow"}}`)
   var m Map
   e := json.Unmarshal(y, &m)
   if e != nil {
      return nil, e
   }
   return m.M("metadata"), nil
}

func main() {
   m, e := Metadata()
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
   s := m.S("title")
   println(s == "Stack Overflow")
}
```

Then whenever you need to index, you just call the appropriate method depending on what you are wanting to return. You can also add Slice if need be `[]interface{}`, and further methods from what I put, for example if you need to return integer. Finally, if you want to check if Map contains key, you can do this:

```
if m["title"] != nil {
   s := m.S("title")
   println(s == "Stack Overflow")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have nested JSON/response

```
mdi, err := page. Metadata()
title, ok := mdi.(map[string]interface{})["key2"].(map[string]interface{})["title"]
fmt.Println(title)
```