# How to access Elastic response values in Go

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm using go-elasticsearch which is the official package for elastic. This is my Elastic response:

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
    ]
  },
  "suggest": {
    "compeletion-suggest": [
      {
        "text": "txt",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 3,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "sometext_result1",
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "id1",
            "_score": 2.0,
            "_source": {
              "content_completion": {
                "input": [
                  "sometext_result1"
                ],
                "weight": 2
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "text": "sometext_result2",
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "id2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
              "content_completion": {
                "input": [
                  "sometext_result2"
                ],
                "weight": 1
              }
            }
          },
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to iterate over "options" and I've already tried this:

```
var (
    r  map[string]interface{}
)

es, err := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()

var buf bytes.Buffer
query := map[string]interface{}{
    "suggest": map[string]interface{}{
        "compeletion-suggest": map[string]interface{}{
            "prefix": "txt",
            "completion": map[string]interface{}{
                "field": "content_completion",
            },
        },
    },
}
if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(query); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error encoding query: %s", err)
}

res, err = es.Search(
    es.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
    es.Search.WithIndex("myindex"),
    es.Search.WithBody(&buf),
    es.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
    es.Search.WithPretty(),
)

defer res.Body.Close()

if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
}

for _, suggestion := range r["suggest"].(map[string]interface{})["compeletion-suggest"].([]interface{}) {
    options := suggestion.(map[string]interface{})["options"]
    for _, option := range options {
        log.Printf(" * option=%s", option)
    }
}
```

It throws this error at 3rd line of the last for loop:

**cannot range over options (type interface {})**

```
for _, suggestion := range r["suggest"].(map[string]interface{})["compeletion-suggest"].([]interface{}) {
    options := suggestion.(map[string]interface{})["options"]
    for _, option := range options {
        log.Printf(" * option=%s", option)
    }
}
```

I'm new to Go. I need to know how to access elastic response fields. For example, How can I read _id field of options?

Comment: The JSON data seems to be not entirely correct. You can use a [tool like this one](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert your data to struct definition. Then you can use that structure more easily. If you don't want to go this route, you somewhere range over a variable named `temp` (not shown in your code), but it is of type `interface{}` (empty interface). You need to do a type assertion to a list type (or map) there, otherwise it won't compile. The way with structs is however way easier to read and write.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer and your solution is really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elasticsearch response which you've posted as JSON seems to not entirely correct (few brackets are missing and bad indentation) I've made an edit though, so no need to worry.

Coming to loop issue, this how your for-loop should like:

```
for _, suggestion := range r["suggest"].(map[string]interface{})["compeletion-suggest"].([]interface{}) {
    options := suggestion.(map[string]interface{})["options"]

    for _, option := range options.([]interface{}) {
        log.Printf(" * option=%s", option)
    }
}
```

You forget to mention range like this `options.([]interface{})`

This gives me output like this:

```
2020/06/28 23:57:03  * option=map[_id:id1 _index:myindex _score:%!s(float64=2) _source:map[content_completion:map[input:[sometext_result1] weight:%!s(float64=2)]] _type:_doc text:sometext_result1]
2020/06/28 23:57:03  * option=map[_id:id2 _index:myindex _score:%!s(float64=1) _source:map[content_completion:map[input:[sometext_result2] weight:%!s(float64=1)]] _type:_doc text:sometext_result2]
```

I hope this is what you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: Thanks! one more question: How can I access fields of option, for example, text or _id?
More generally, How can I make a nice JSON out of it?

Comment: This is a kind of map. To access fields, I may suggest you to go through this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214037/7299340

Comment: If you still face issue to access a field, let me know. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Harshit. I found what I was looking for based on your answer and link.